# codeigniter not returning json/ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have read a lot on codeIgniter ajax response. I have and modified my ajax script multiple times yet codeIgniter does not return the json response although I see the response when debugging with firefox developer browser under the network tab of web console. here's what i have written

**AJAX script**

```
$("#class_id").change(function(){

    var class_id = $("#class_id").val();
    alert(class_id);
    alert("<?php echo base_url(); ?>teacher/index.php?teacher/set_class_id");
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>teacher/index.php?teacher/set_class_id",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {class_id: class_id},

            success: function(response) {
                $("#res").html(reponse.class_id);
            }
    });
    return false;

});
```

**controller**

```
function set_class_id()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('teacher_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');

        //echo "dsdsd".$this->input->POST('class_id');
        if (!empty($this->input->POST('class_id')))
        {
            $page_data = array('class_id' => $this->input->POST('class_id'));
            //$response["JSON"] = json_encode($page_data);
            $response = array('class_id' => $this->input->POST('class_id'));

            echo json_encode($page_data);

            $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);

        }
}
```

Comment: why are u using `$this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);` ??? after echo

Comment: getting value here? `//echo "dsdsd".$this->input->POST('class_id');`?

Comment: without your response, how can we help u

Comment: This is confusing, you are sending data to another page? I mean after you throw data on ajax, what will be the view loaded?

Comment: @devpro yes i see a response in the browser using firebug and i get a response status of 200.

Comment: @devpro I'm using $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data); as a template. all pages load here.

Comment: @Roshan i had the same thought that processing a different function that isnt the view's name function may be the problem. the view is called marks and the ajax is processing set_class_id which is supposed to be a view according to the rules of codeigniter

Comment: @Roshan I just put the code in marks method. I still have the same experience

Comment: but this will not work when u are echo json response

Comment: @devpro what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `//echo "dsdsd".$this->input->POST('class_id');` are u getting values here?

Comment: yes i am. but i see the values with firebug

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

Also, check th output class for more info [Codeigniter Output Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html)

Comment: yes i have then i get this response `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a way out. using just php, I sent the class_id to the controller using a submit button then checked for the response on the page to enable the subject dropdown. Although i haven't figured why the ajax isn't working yet. thanks guys for your inputs